# Segfault initializing reference variable on stack in gtest

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, containers, heap-memory

I'm creating a test for my TwoDArray container and I'm getting a segfault. The TwoDArray object initializes fine on the heap but when I try to test it on the stack, I get a segfault. It uses a vector on the heap as the underlying container. I initialized a vector perfectly fine but the TwoDArray object gives a segfault as soon as it runs.

I've cut out the functions as I'm mostly concerned with initialization.

```
 21 template<typename T>
 22 class TwoDArray{
 23 
 24   private:
 25     int numRows;
 26     int numCols;
 27     std::vector<T> * vecPtr; // Underlying container
 28 
 29   public:
 30     TwoDArray(){ TwoDArray( DEF_ROW_SIZE, DEF_COL_SIZE ); }

 ...

 40     TwoDArray( int m, int n ):numRows(m), numCols(n),
 41                               vecPtr(new std::vector<T>(m*n)){ }

 ...

 43     /* Destructor that specifies the size of the 2D Array
 44      */
 45     ~TwoDArray(){ delete vecPtr; }
 ...
```

then the actual test:

```
  2 #include <vector>
  3 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
  4 #include "TwoDArray.hpp"
  5 
  6 class TestTwoDArray : public testing::Test{
  7   public:
  8 
  9     TwoDArray<int> arr1;
 10     std::vector<int> vec;
 11 
 12     virtual void SetUp(){
 14     }
 15 
 16     virtual void TestDown(){
 17     }
 18 };
 19 
 20 TEST_F( TestTwoDArray, validSizeTest ){
 21   //arr1 = TwoDArray<int>();
 22   
 24 }
 25 

 30 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 31   TwoDArray<int> arr1;
 32   testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
 33   return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
 34 }
```

I have another class that creates the object fine on the heap. Here line 9 gives the segfault. But line 31 doesn't. Maybe I'm not understanding how to initialize something.

Comment: If you are on linux try running the code with sanitizers

Comment: `TwoDArray(){ TwoDArray( DEF_ROW_SIZE, DEF_COL_SIZE ); }` -- Explain in your own words what this does, just to see if you understand what that line is actually doing.

Comment: *I initialized a vector perfectly fine* -- You didn't really check -- you were not initializing the vector perfectly fine.  Second, why are you using `new vector` anyway?  You don't need `new` or pointers to have a vector as a member.  All you need is `std::vector<int> vecPtr;` and just `vecPtr(m*n)` in the member initialization list.

Comment: Thanks, it seems when I was cleaning my code I missed this. I know its not necessary. I was initializing on the heap because it's my understanding, maybe misunderstanding, that it handles very large objects better. If not, what are the benefits of one vs the other?

Answer (score 1):

Your default constructor doesn't do what you think it does.  It leaves the various member variables uninitialized, then creates a temporary `TwoDArray` object.

What you want for a delegating constructor is

```
TwoDArray(): TwoDArray( DEF_ROW_SIZE, DEF_COL_SIZE ) { }
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you!